# What does "find" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What does "find" mean in football (soccer) context?

90+2: Bernardo **finds** Torres in the box but his shot is well blocked.

Riyad Mahrez **finds** the bottom corner.

GOAL! MANCHESTER CITY 1-0 Southampton (De Bruyne)
14 min: Their first attack and their first goal. A brilliant long ball from Dias **finds** Zinchenko and he picks out Foden in the middle. His shot is saved by McCarthy but he can only push it out to De Bruyne who just keeps his shot under the bar.

Comment: What makes you think the definition in a football context is different from a generic definition?

Comment: It means that a player kicks the ball accurately to a team mate, often in difficult conditions when the team mate is surrounded by opposing players.

Answer (score 1):

*Find* can mean discovering something by chance, but it can also mean a directed effort to search for something, to locate it. And that could just be learning where something is, but it can also mean physically getting to that thing.

You tend to hear this meaning used a lot for hitting a target, in a literal and figurative sense (e.g. *the insult found its mark*).  That's basically how it's being used in these examples - although *a brilliant long ball from Dias finds Zinchenko* could imply the ball luckily ended up near that player (calling it *brilliant* sounds like it was aimed though).